# Ordering rows in R

Tags: r

I have a question about ordering data in R:

```
data<-letters
data<-sample(data)
order<-c(1:26)
data<-as.data.frame(cbind(data,order))
data<-arrange(data,order)

data$order

[1] 1  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 2  20 21 22 23 24 25 26 3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

How can I make the order be as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The monstrosity that is `as.data.frame(cbind())` strikes again. There is a function for creating data frames. It's called `data.frame()`. Use it! ;)

```
data<-data.frame(data = data,order = order)
data<-arrange(data,order)
```

When you `cbind` a factor (or character) with a numeric vector, as documented in `?cbind`, you'll get a matrix, and hence lots of probably unwanted coercion.

Answer (score 3):

DON'T USE as.data.frame(cbind(data,order))  # just use either `data.frame` or `as.data.frame`

And please throw away any tutorial that taught you that. It's an abomination!

Answer (score 0):

When you `cbind` elements, they must be all the same type, when you combined those characters and numeric values in the `as.data.frame` command, you forced everything to character and then when you make a data.frame they are converted to factors. Those are sorted lexicographical by default. If you want them to sort like numbers, I suggest you keep them as numbers. So

```
data<-data.frame(data,order)
```

Is a better choice. Alternative, you can convert the character values of the labels to numeric and sort

```
data<-arrange(data,as.numeric(as.character(order)))
```

but that's a lot of unnecessary work.

Answer (score 0):

`sort(data)` should do this just fine. Check out `?sort` as there is an argument to chose ascending or descending.